# Typescript generic interfaces match on property value

Tags: typescript, generics, interface

I am still learning TypeScript and all the features it has. One of which is constraining generics. I apologize if this is a commonly asked question, if you have any resources(beyond the docs) that can help me get better at this, please link as comment.

What I'm trying to do is, have the `type` properties match between my `DeliveryObject` and all the objects inside of `deliveryItems`.

Here's an example of code that compiles, but just isn't the end solution that I'm looking for.

```js
type DeliveryMethod = 'notification' | 'text' | 'email'

type DeliveryActions = INotificationAction | ITextMessageAction | IEmailAction

interface IDelivery {
  type: DeliveryMethod
}

interface INotificationAction extends IDelivery {
  type: 'notification'
  deviceId: string
  message: string
}

interface ITextMessageAction extends IDelivery {
  type: 'text'
  message: string
}

interface IEmailAction extends IDelivery {
  type: 'email'
  to: string
  subject: string
  body: string
}

// I know I need to do something additional here...
interface IDeliveryObject<T extends DeliveryMethod, U extends DeliveryActions> {
  type: T
  deliveryItems: Array<U>
}

function sendDelivery<K extends DeliveryMethod, Z extends DeliveryActions>(state: IDeliveryObject<K, Z>) {
  console.log(state)
}

sendDelivery({
  type: 'notification', // <--- needs to match or error out
  deliveryItems: [
    {
      type: 'email',  // <--- needs to match or error out
      to: 'fake@email.com',
      subject: '1235-67890',
      body: 'Here is a notification'
    }
  ]
})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would approach this by using a "type lookup map" to tie together the delivery method and it's associated action object. So I would add another type like this:

```
type DeliveryActionTypes = {
    "notification": INotificationAction;
    "text": ITextMessageAction;
    "email": IEmailAction;
}
```

That type just maps the correct method name to it's action object type. Then you can replace the declarations for `DeliveryMethod` and `DeliveryActions` with:

```
type DeliveryMethod = keyof DeliveryActionTypes;
type DeliveryActions = DeliveryActionTypes[keyof DeliveryActionTypes];
```

That will allow you to easily lookup the correct action if you know the name of the method. You can use that in your `IDeliveryObject` to make sure that the two types correspond:

```
interface IDeliveryObject<T extends DeliveryMethod> {
    type: T;

    // This is the type lookup, note the `DeliveryActionTypes[T]` part.
    deliveryItems: Array<DeliveryActionTypes[T]>;
}
```

Now you can simplify the signature for the `sendDelivery` function, since all it needs now is the method name:

```
function sendDelivery<K extends DeliveryMethod>(state: IDeliveryObject<K>) {
  console.log(state)
}
```

---

With all that, you'll get an error if the types don't match:

```
sendDelivery({
  type: 'notification',
  deliveryItems: [
    {
      type: 'email', 
      to: 'fake@email.com', // <-- error on this line, see below
      subject: '1235-67890',
      body: 'Here is a notification'
    }
  ]
})
```

> ```
> Type '{ type: "email"; to: string; subject: string; body: string; }'
> is not assignable to type 'INotificationAction'.
> ```

As you can see, Typescript correctly concludes that the items in the array should be of type `INotificationAction`, and produces an error when they are not.

Comment: Beautiful answer @CRice! Thank you!